# FastClick and click() event trigger trouble

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, webkit

I have trouble when I include [FastClick](http://ftlabs.github.io/fastclick/) in my proj. All works fine and 300ms delay on mobile devices is lost but programmatically triggering click() event doesnt work on mobile now.

Comment: Try triggering `tap` event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says this in the documentation (well, the page you linked under advanced)

> This is where the needsclick class comes in. Add the class to any element that requires a non-synthetic click.

So add the class `needsclick` to the elements you want to manual trigger "click" with

Comment: looks like 'needsclick' is ignored me

Comment: 300ms delay returns but click() trigger is not working.

Comment: Could you edit in the code and the element with the event you are trying to trigger?

Answer (score -1):

I had exactly the same problem and at the end I got rid of FastClick and did my own simple solution after some problems with fastclick when triggering click events. This example uses jQuery.

```
$(document).on('touchstart', '.clickable', function(e){
    // This prevents the click to be completed
    // so will prevent the annoying flickering effect
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

You have to add .clickable class to any element you want to take out the 300m delay from.

Then, change all click events for touchstart events, so this

```
$('#elementid').click(function(e){
   console.log('ex event'); 
}
```

has to be now this

```
$(document).on('touchstart', '#elementid', function(e){
   console.log('new event'); 
}
```